# Activerecord - callback after all associated objects are saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model and I would like to store ids of associated objects (denormalize) for performance reasons. I have a method which looks like this:

```
def cache_ids
  self._tag_ids = self.tag_ids
end
```

I thought I could just run it on before_save, however there is a problem - some of the associated objects might be new records, and therefore they will not have ids.

Then I switched to after_save, but apparently this callback is also triggered before the transaction is committed, so ids are still not set.

At the moment I ended up with:

```
def save_with_idcache(*args)
  return false unless save_without_idcache(*args)

  cache_ids

  return save_without_idcache(false)
end

alias_method_chain :save, :idcache
```

Which seems to work but doesn't look very elegant.

Is there any better way? Like, a callback after the object and associated objects are all saved?

Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you are trying to do but it smells a little to me. Getting the ids of associated elements can be done with a single querty ... ?

Comment: I agree with Toby, you can pull of the associated objects or ids back in a single query. What is the driver to cache them?

Answer (score 1):

You might try it in reverse - have the associated objects update their parent's `_tag_ids` in `after_create`, `after_save` (if they are removed from the association and/or added to a new one) and `after_destroy`.

Whether or not this is a better solution would depend on how many of them there are, how much you're moving them around, and how careful you want to be about dirty attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use after_create as well? The id will be there.

```
after_create :idcache
before_save :idcache

protected
def idcache
  unless new_record?
    ...
  end
end
```